# Why I training FER2013 ,but the model I get is inaccurate?

Tags: python, resnet

we use resnet 101 to train it ,however we can not get the accuracy more than 60 ,why?
I have tried it many times ,however,none of it have more than 60%.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: batchsz=32
lr = 1e-4
epochs =20
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
torch.manual_seed(1234)
train_db=Data('train_data',224,mode='train')
val_db=Data('train_data',224,mode='val')
test_db=Data('train_data',224,mode='test')
train_loader=DataLoader(train_db,batch_size=batchsz,shuffle=True,num_workers=4)
val_loader=DataLoader(val_db,batch_size=batchsz,num_workers=4)
test_loader=DataLoader(test_db,batch_size=batchsz,num_workers=4)
viz=visdom.Visdom()

Comment: def evalute(model,loader):
 model.eval()
 correct=0
 total=len(loader.dataset)
 for x,y in loader:
  x,y =x.to(device),y.to(device)
  with torch.no_grad():
   logits=model(x)
   pred=logits.argmax(dim=1)
  correct+=torch.eq(pred,y).sum().float().item()
 return correct / total

Comment: trained_model=resnet101(pretrained=True)
 model = nn.Sequential(*list(trained_model.children())[:-1],Flatten(),nn.Linear(512,6)).to(device)
 optimizer=optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=lr)
 criteon=nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

Comment: for step,(x,y) in enumerate(train_loader):
   x,y = x.to(device),y.to(device)
   model.train()
   logits=model(x)
   loss=criteon(logits,y)
   optimizer.zero_grad()
   loss.backward()
   optimizer.step()
   viz.line([[loss.item(),evalute(model,val_loader)]],[global_step],win='test',update='append')
   global_step+=1